# How to make ClosedXML to not break words?

Tags: closedxml

I am constructing an Excel document using ClosedXML.

I fill the cells with text. When the text is long, it breaks it into several lines in the middle of the word.

How can I make it break into lines only between the words, only on the white spaces?

For example: The word Establishment is broken into 2 and the column width is not changed. I don't want it to break words in two but only in between words and if necessary to increase column width.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (c#):

```
ws.Cells().Style.Alignment.SetWrapText(true);
```

where ws is the worksheet.

Comment: I have edited my question and I put also an image.

I have put SetWrapText, but still when there is a long word it breaks it in 2 lines. I don't want it to break the words, but only between the words. I want it if necessary to increase column width to fit the whole word.